# Click on an image but it loads another image in a pop up without going to a new page using HTML?

Tags: html

i have been trying to code using html, where there is an image file, and upon clicking the image, it will pop up a different image in the same screen but in a separate window with specified width and height.

Currently, i'm only able to display an enlarged version of the same pic when i click.

below is the simple code where i'm trying to click on the image of "spoon of cereal", and for the image of "honey" to be displayed in a pop up window in the same screen when i click. but it displays the honey picture in a new page instead, and I will need to press back to go back to the page.

How would I need to code such that when i click on the "spoon of cereal" pic, it will still remain at that page, but a popup of the "honey" pic will show in its original dimension?

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Runny_hunny.jpg" target="_self" imageanchor="1">
<img border="0" height="104" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Spoonful_of_cereal.jpg" width="150" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to do something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<img border="0" height="104"     src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Spoonful_of_cereal.jpg" onclick="MyWindow=window.open('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Runny_hunny.jpg','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300')" width="150" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

You can change all the options in there. [Reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: hello, thanks alot! its what i was looking for! i'm currently now experimenting the available options. sadly I couldn't remove the address bar as its only suppported for Opera browsers.

Comment: Okay cool. In addition, to do what you asked and size the window to fit the image... personally I am not aware of an easy solution to this. There may be a CSS fix, but you may have to use javascript for something like that.

Comment: ok noted. thanks for the tip. i'm trying to avoid CSS or javascript if possible to keep it as basic as possible. oh and one more thing. I've seen some websites where they are able to enlarge a picture via popup, and by clicking outside the popup picture, it will close the popup picture instead of clicking the "X" at the top right corner of the window. Is that possible to be coded using html?